# How do I get element.onclick working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, events, click

I cant figure this out for the life of me.

I've dynamically created an element and i need to add a click event to it though it needs to work in all browsers right up to ie7.

```
var bottle = document.createElement('a');
bottle.id = 'target';
bottle.onclick = function(){makeClickable();};
//bottle.setAttribute('onclick', 'makeClickable();');
bottle.setAttribute('title', 'Lavender');
bottle.setAttribute('class', 'lavenderButton');
bottle.setAttribute('style', '**MY STYLES**');
bottle.innerHTML = "<div class='button pulse lavenderBottleImg'><img width='100%' src='**SOURCE**' class='indicator'></div>";
document.body.appendChild(bottle);
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfGSR/1/). It's modified slightly: `makeClickable()` is defined to output a message to the JavaScript console, and the image element inside the div is replaced with text.

The onclick works, but not in Firefox! How do I get the onclick to work across all browsers?

The commented out option didn't work in IE7 (it's important it works there!) and adding an event listener didnt work either.

Phew! What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: Are you getting an error or is nothing happening at all?

Comment: Consider using `addEventListener` for event binding https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: no errors at all. doesnt do anything

Comment: first append element and then add event handler

Comment: Unfortunately i cant use jquery for this one

Comment: @alex23 If they arent using it in the handler, then theres no reason to do that in any browser

Comment: @Givi order should not matter.

Comment: @DustinSilk please try posting an example of this not working in js fiddle

Comment: @alex23 The point is that defining parameters has no effect on a function definition unless theyre being used. It shouldnt be suggeted because it **isn't** a possibility for the problem. Specifically in this situation

Comment: @alex23 even though the parameter is always passed to the callback function, that doesn't mean that the function needs to define the argument.

Comment: I proposed an edit with [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfGSR/1/). It seems to work fine in Firefox.

Comment: okay, i'm so sorry, its was a stupid mistake on my part >.<
But making a jsfiddle did help me find the issue.

Comment: bottle.onclick = function(){makeClickable();}; worked

Comment: @DustinSilk I'm confused - isn't that what your original code was? Also, it's not really necessary to use `.setAttribute()` unless you actually need the attribute later. It's perfectly fine to just set the property, like you do for `onclick` - so you could use `bottle.title = "Lavender";`

Answer (score 2):

The `onclick` event works fine as you have it. I've just run it, using an `alert()` instead of `makeClickable()`.  This would suggest that the problem isn't with the way you've coded the `click` event but with something in `makeClickable()`.

[Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/F6DM8/)